# How to make an operator to access custom screen, scene, brushes, etc

Tags: python

I want to make an operator (to put in a menu) to be able to select custom scenes, screens, brushes, etc.  I look in the info panel when I switch to one, but Blender doesn't display how it switches to these items.

Comment: just a note : your questions have been confusing and not clear so please try to be more descriptive and precise

Comment: I found the answer screen operators at http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?246232-Screen-Layout-Hotkeys